# Set language for the session dynamically

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-synapse, parse-error

I am having trouble parameterizing the language variable in a stored procedure. I am writing a procedure to create date dimension table and would like to have a "language" parameter.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), this should be possible by creating a variable of type `sysname`.

However, executing the following code results in an error:

```sql
DECLARE @Language sysname;
SET @Language = 'Spanish';
SET LANGUAGE @Language;
```

> Parse error at line: 1, column: 20: Incorrect syntax near 'N'Spanish''.

I noticed that I can execute the command with dynamic SQL, although this doesn't actually change the language which seems extra strange.

For example:

```sql
SET LANGUAGE English

EXEC('SET LANGUAGE Spanish') -- this doesn't work
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS MonthName

SET LANGUAGE Spanish -- this works
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS MonthName
```

Returns:

| MonthName |
| --- |
| July |

| MonthName |
| --- |
| Julio |

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to generate localized strings in the database in the first place? That's where the problem begins. You won't solve it by hard-coding locales and languages. Formatting dates into strings is the job of the *client* or *report engine*, not the database

Comment: `create date dimension table` create and store the strings you want in the dimension table itself. That's one of the most important reasons this table exists. Not only to allow easier aggregations, but also provide the *reporting labels* for items. This is a common guidance for dimensions in general. The labels generated by a database server won't be the same ones used by your business. Especially not fiscal periods. It's *very* common to have multiple sets of label columns, one per target language. Page/columnstore compression eliminate the storage costs *and* improve IO performance

Comment: In the dimension creation script you can use T-SQL's `FORMAT` with a culture parameter to generate the localized strings you want, for all the languages you need. `FORMAT` is slow but the dimension script only has to run once. *DON'T* try to use `FORMAT` in the reporting queries though, because you'll pay that performance penalty

Comment: The dynamic sql has own scope, so if you want your language to "stick" you have to add rest of the code inside the dynamic sql string as well. With that being said, what @PanagiotisKanavos said :D

Comment: If I remember correctly, the SSAS or SSIS date dimension wizard even offers to add labels in multiple languages

Comment: I will store the strings in the dimension table. I would just like to have the options to select the language before populating the table with data. Ideally, this would be read from some configuration table so that all settings will be stored in one place.

Comment: @NaceKapus you're *selecting* data, not inserting it. Client applications use *their* locale when converting binary date values to strings for display, often automatically. They don't ask the database to do it. The date dimension is created *once* anyway, not every time an application runs. That's the whole point of it.

Comment: Instead of using `DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE())`, use `FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MMMM' , 'fr-FR')`, The culture itself can be an argument, eg `declare @culture nvarchar(10)='de';
select FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MMMM' , @culture)`